# prediction in tobit survival model

Tags: survival-analysis

Consider a tobit model:
   ln(T) = xb + e
where e~ iid N(0,s2). Abusing notation,
we get ML estimates b and s2.

Now suppose we want an estimate
(prediction) of T. As I understand it,
the usual procedure is to exponentiate the
linear predictor, ie estimate T by exp(xb).
But isn't this wrong? If the tobit model
holds, then
   T = exp(xb)exp(e)
and if e is normal, then exp(e) is
lognormal, with an expectation that
isn't unity but instead depends on
(the estimate of) s2. Shouldn't we
take this into account when doing
a prediction?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I may be able to answer my own question. When we do exp(bx) we're basing the prediction on the *median*, not the mean.